# Can we use normal react jsx with Material UI ? Or we have to use typescirpt

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jsx

Does material UI require typescript or we can write react jsx code and it will work. I could not find answer to this question elsewhere so I came here.

Comment: It does not require typescript

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can write react jsx code and it will work.